# Load dotenv file into current cmd shell session?

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a dotenv file, `my_file.env`, and it's contents are as following:

```
FIRST_VALUE=a value
SECOND_VALUE=2
```

In the Windows shell, `cmd.exe`, I would like to to load this into it's current shell session.

How would one do this?

Comment: It would be prudent to enclose each line in QUOTATION MARK characters. This will prevent unseen whitespace (SPACE, TAB, etc) from being used at the end of the line. `"FIRST_VALUE=a value"`

Comment: @lit I would disagree and say that it is the responsibility of whatever that is reading it to trim it. You might be dynamically generating these things and you could end up with `"FIRST_VALUE=a value     "`. You could also argue the space is supposed to be there and should not be trimmed at all. That is the choice of whoever is using it.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "eol= delims=" %i in ('type "C:/my_file.env"') do set %i
```

Comment: There are a lot of commands/parameters here for a code-only post. Please add some explanation for what each part of this code does.

Comment: You haven't tested this. The first line in the test file contains a space   so you need to quote the 2nd `%i%

Comment: When using in a batch, we need to double the percentage character, so: "%%i" instead of "%i". But in the command line, it is working like above.